# Проблема с установкой opencart в OC linux

Tags: linux, веб-программирование, opencart, permissions, install

Помогите разобраться с установкой opencart
операционая система *linux*[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Установите curl (sudo apt-get install curl) и zip (apt-get install zip unzip).

И выставите права:

```
sudo chmod 664 /var/www/html/opencart/upload/config.php 
sudo chmod 664 /var/www/html/opencart/upload/admin/config.php
```

У меня выставлено 664. Если не поможет - то замените на 775

на папки таким образом:
sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html/upload/{название папки}